# Making mailto links from SQL database

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm attempting to make our intranet page more useful. It was written many years ago by someone who hasn't worked here in almost as many years.

I've redone alot of the pages and one of the pages is a contact refrences list. I added an email field to the database that holds all the information, modified the page to take on the additional columns and I can post the data to the page successfully. The problem is, I cannot make the links work for email, I've tried several different methods for this and each has caused the entire page to fail, I also have been unsuccessful in finding another posting that has the 3 conditions I'm looking for: written in ASP, creates mailto links AND is pulling from an external database. Lot's of posts about ASP mailto links but all show putting the address into the coding which doesn't work for me.

Here's the coding I'm using to pull the data currently without links:

```
<%if pls.Fields.Item("Email").Value <> "" then
  Response.Write(pls.Fields.Item("Email").Value)
  else
  Response.Write("&nbsp;")
  end if %>
```

The SQL table allows for NULL entries in the email as not all contacts have an email address so the IF statement listed above puts in a space if the address is NULL otherwise I get broken borders where the empty fields are.

How do I create an IF statement that will create a link when an email is present and use that email address?

Comment: Any way you can post an example of your code as it appears in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very general idea of what you need. I would personally add a bit more checking to the code that looks at the "Email" field, eg ensure it looks like a valid email address, check for null, things like that, but the idea using VB.NET coding might look like this:

```
If pls.Fields.Item("Email").Value<>"" Then
    Response.Write("<A HREF='mailto:" + pls.Fields.Item("Email").Value + "'>Click for email</A>"
Else
    Response.Write("")
End If
```

Comment: I've tried a similar coding in my initial attempts and I tried copying your coding and pasting it in but alas it just breaks the page again, just get the generic "This page cannot be displayed" message.

Comment: When are you seeing this error? *None* of the page displays? Or does this happen when you click the link created by the code? A screen-snip might be very helpful.

Comment: When you open the page that the code is on, there's no link to click because the whole page is broken.